# Could not find module 'tns-core-modules/globals'

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am new to Native Script. Trying to create Hello World application using below link

http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-1

build success but run failed [error code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWwDH.png)

I have tried in 2-3 system same result, please help

Comment: Can you provide the output of tns --version and ng --version?

Comment: tns version : 2.4.2, angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 6.10.3
os: darwin x64

Comment: being on the beta of angular-cli could be an issue, also you are not on the latest for tns. I would try upgrading

Comment: Thanks Richard after upgrading working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to latest versions of TNS and Angular to be compatible with the Sample Application.